# Follow one user in one column in tweetdeck

Tags: tweetdeck

**In desktop Tweetdeck, how can I follow one user in one column?** It's gotta be something *dead-simple*, but for the life of me, I cannot get the hang of that application's user interface. Too out of what I'm used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible (any more?). As a workaround, you can probably create private lists and add each user you want to follow to a list. Then click on `Add Column` -> `Groups/Lists` -> Select the list.